# Logging not happening with log4j when I export my java project into runnable jar

Tags: java, logging, log4j, runnable-jar

I have configured log4j for my standalone java project. It works fine when I run the project in eclipse(logging happens). But when I export the project into Runnable jar file I'm not able to get the logging in the log file. I tried running the jar from command line, the flow works fine but I don't get any errors wrt log4j and the logging does not happen.

Comment: As a note, log4j is generally obsolete; slf4j is the common API now, and Logback or other backends are usual.

Comment: Can you paste here your log4j configuration?